# How to remove footer in webview in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native so can somebody please help me to remove the footer from the webview.
I am using expo.

```
import React from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

const Home = () => {
  const loading = () => {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        size="large"
        style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center" }}
      />
    );
  };


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://www.collectiveoutlet.co.nz/" }}
        renderLoading={loading()}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run javascript in the webview, here an example: https://snack.expo.io/@stealkiller06/1a0b7b

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";


// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {

  const runFirst = `
let selector = document.querySelector("div#shopify-section-footer")

selector.style.display = "none"
   
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://www.collectiveoutlet.co.nz/" }}
        injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

});
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I don’t want an alert or a message. I want to remove the footer of the page of the url

Comment: It was just an example, I just edit the answer, check it out

Comment: its showing an error of unrecognized selector sent to instance. I want to remove the class by the name of (div#shopify-section-footer) from the url.

Comment: And i even tried using this `document.querySelector('div#shopify-section-footer').remove();`

Comment: Look at the example my friend again, I attached the project using the code and also gave you the code, I hope this could solve your problem.

Comment: No it doesn't. I ran your code but the footer is still there.I tried modifying it but it still doesn't work. I think it is not able to recognize document. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please check the link, there is the example and I ran on my device and It worked, make sure that you did it right. Test the example here:https://snack.expo.io/@stealkiller06/1a0b7b

Comment: It’s working on android but not on iPhone. I was trying it on iPhone device. I just tried using android phone and it worked. Why isn’t it working on iPhone.

Comment: yes it worked now. Thank you.Just one last thing can you please tell me what to do if I want to add an if else statement in this.